# How to click on send button on whatsapp using Selenium xpath or css in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, whatsapp

How can use whatsapp xpath or css(Chromedriver) in vb.net.

HTML:

```
<span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class>...</span> ==$0
```

xpath:

```
//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div/span[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button/span
```

I tried but not working:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[data-testid='send' data-icon='send']")).Click()
```

Comment: Could someone answer this question

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML:

```
<span data-testid="send" data-icon="send" class>...</span>
```

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  Driver.FindElementByCss("span[data-testid='send'][data-icon='send']").Click()
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  Driver.FindElementByXPath("//span[@data-testid='send' and @data-icon='send']").Click()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on the element using Selenium and VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62375148/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

it should be like

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[data-testid='send'][data-icon='send']")).Click()
```

when select specific attributes :

```
span[data-testid='send']
```

to add attributes to same tag :

```
span[data-testid='send'][data-icon='send']
```

*no space between attributes